# Number column in oracle with ftBCD datatype parameter in ADO occurs "Unspecified error" (Oracle Provider for OleDB)

Tags: oracle, delphi, oledb, ado, tclientdataset

I have programing a delphi with ADO + DataSetProvider + ClientDataSet. In ApplyUpdates of the ClientDataSet, this generate the ADOcommand with parameters based in fields datatypes.

When a parameter is ftBCD, occurs "Unspecified error". If you change datatype for ftFloat, ftExtended or ftCurrency, the command is executed successfully. But the datatype of parameter cannot change using ADO+ClientDataSet. The provider used is "Oracle Provider for OleDB".

The "Microsoft provider OleDB for oracle" execute without problems, but is very slow and I have problems with CLOB column. The oracle is 11g and the client is 11.2.0.2.

The Delphi is Delphi XE. Sample code for error:

```
vAdo := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
vAdo.LoginPrompt := false;
vAdo.ConnectionString := 'Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=HR;Data Source=server/orcl;Extended Properties=""';
vAdo.Connected := True;

vAdoCommando := TADOCommand.Create(nil);
vAdoCommando.Connection := vAdo;
vAdoCommando.CommandText := 'UPDATE HD_PRIORIDADE SET TEMPORESPOSTA = ? WHERE HANDLE = ? ';

vParametro := vAdoCommando.Parameters.AddParameter;
vParametro.DataType := ftBCD;
vParametro.Value     := 12.3;
vParametro := vAdoCommando.Parameters.AddParameter;
vParametro.Value := 1;

vAdoCommando.ExecuteOptions := [eoExecuteNoRecords];
vAdoCommando.Execute(vResult, EmptyParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution, but may be a workaround.

Instead of a `TADOCommand`, try with `TADOQuery`; and don't create the param, let the ADO do it for you with `ParseSQL`. An example:

```
qryUpdPrioridade:= TADOQuery.Create(nil)
try
  qryUpdPrioridade.Connection:= vAdo;
  qryUpdPrioridade.SQL.Add('UPDATE HD_PRIORIDADE SET');
  qryUpdPrioridade.SQL.Add('  TEMPORESPOSTA = :TEMPORESPOSTA');
  qryUpdPrioridade.SQL.Add('WHERE HANDLE = :HANDLE');
  qryUpdPrioridade.Parameters.ParseSQL(qryUpdPrioridade.SQL.Text, True);

  qryUpdPrioridade.Parameters.ParamByName('TEMPORESPOSTA').Value:= 12.3;
  qryUpdPrioridade.Parameters.ParamByName('HANDLE').Value:= 1;

  try
    qryUpdPrioridade.ExecSQL;
  except
    On E: Exception do
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Falha na atualização:'#13#10'%s: %s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]);
  end;
finally
  qryUpdPrioridade.Free;
end;
```

NOTE: I don't have IDE a this moment, may be there are some incorrect code. I can correct tomorrow morning.

Comment: For commands executed directly, simply do not use DataTypes not compatible (or generate errors) with Oracle. The problem is that the architecture uses "ADO + DataSetProvider + ClientDataSet", which automatically generates a ADOCommand.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to this problem have used for months in architecture `ADO` + `DataSetProvider` + `ClientDataSet`., a `TADOQuery` inherited, and override the method `PSExecuteStatement`. The code is same overrided, only replacing the `DataType` that generate errors with Oracle before executing the command (`ftBCD`, etc --> `ftFloat`).